# How to enable/disable nhibernate enverse at runtime

Tags: nhibernate

I need to write history only in several cases. Is it possible to disable or enable enverse at runtime? Something like this, for example:
using (new WriteHistory())
{
}

Comment: then you need to extend the listeners envers uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Firo pointed out, inherit AuditEventListener (which contains the event listeners) and override OnPostInsert, OnPostUpdate, OnPostDelete, OnPreUpdateCollection, OnPreRemoveCollection and OnPostRecreateCollection. In these methods, look if X is fulfilled - if it is, call the base impl. If not, do nothing. Your AuditEventListener impl you pass into the IntegrationWithEnvers method.